# I want to insert news with multiple categories.i want to insert comma separated category in single file database

Tags: codeigniter

```
<label>Select News Type</label>
                                <?php 
                                foreach($category as $row)
                                {
                                ?>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['category_name'];?>" name="type[]"/>
                                <lable><?php echo $row['category_name'];?></lable>
                                <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>
```

i want to insert comma separated values in single database field plz help for this work

Answer (score 0):

just simple get value from post data

```
$types = $this->input->post('type');
```

it will give you array of all checked categories value simply implode them

```
$comma_seprated = implode(',',$types);
```

this will become string and you can save in database